# Can Google Actions be imported/exported from the Actions Console?

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I'm just starting to learn how to build an Action with Scenes and Intends. Very basic. I see that prompts can be defined in JSON. Is it possible to export the whole Action in JSON format for me to edit it outside of the UI? and then reimport it?

The idea is that if a have a very simple Action (with lots of scenes, but easy intends) I can define the whole action in a much simpler format and automatically create the JSON that could be imported. It would be much faster for me than defining each scene in the Actions Console.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of.

You can use the [gactions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions) command line tool to export and import the configuration files. These completely represent the same things that you can edit using the web-based graphical editor.

However... these files are in YAML, not JSON. Semantically, they're identical, so you will still be able to create something that generates the files.

To [download your configuration](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions/guide#download_actions_from_actions_console) into the **current** directory you'd use the `gactions pull` command and specify your project ID with the `--project-id` parameter:

```
gactions pull --project-id some-project-4242
```

You'll see that the Scenes and Intents each have their own folders under `custom` where you'll be doing your editing.

Once you've made the changes, you can [upload the configuration](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions/guide#push_actions_to_actions_console_project_draft) with

```
gactions push
```

(Note that you can't specify the project ID, since this is in one of the configuration files.)

You can then reload the test simulator and test your changes.

Comment: Thanks, gactions does not have pull/push, it has get/update, but I get an error (where do I get the project-id):   
./gactions list --project actions-codelab
Gactions needs access to your Google account. Please copy & paste the URL [...] back here.
Visit this URL: 
 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?....  
Enter authorization code:
4/1AY0.............
ERROR: Couldn't fetch versions
ERROR: The caller does not have permission
2021/03/07 21:24:24 Server did not return HTTP 200

Comment: ok, I found the project-id, and using -version draft, I can get, but it does not get all the objects, just the action.... pull/push still don't work

Comment: Nevermind... wrong gactions version. I downloaded the right version and it's working just as you explained. THANKS!!!!

Comment: Glad you found the right version! It should be at the link I indicated if anyone else comes along, and yes, there is some authorization required when you start. If the answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.