# Is there a way to export/download/clone a custom Google Assistant Action (as .zip)?

Tags: google-api, google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant

I am trying to export a Google Assistant Action that I have created using the Google Actions Console as a .zip file.

There are several examples of sample Google Assistant projects on Github but I cannot determine how they were able to export the code for their Action. See https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs, particularly the `/src` directory, for an example of the files I would want to export from my Action.

I have attempted to use the `gactions` CLI, particularly the `gactions get --project PROJECT_ID` command, but it does not appear to have the export functionality I am looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: As it turns out, there may be two versions of gactions, only one of which allows you to pull as described in this stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506158/can-google-actions-be-imported-exported-from-the-actions-console

Go to this link and download the appropriate package: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506158/can-google-actions-be-imported-exported-from-the-actions-console. Don't run `gactions.exe` or it may be updated to the later version which does not have the same commands.

This will allow you to pull/push your Google Actions project.

Comment: Can you clarify more specifically what kind of action you have? Is it a smart home action? Dialogflow? Actions Builder?